# moment.js isBetween() unexpectedly returns false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a really simple piece of code for moment.js (see below), it should resolve to true but instead resolves to false.

I get the same unexpected behaviour with isBefore() or isAfter(), which leads me to believe there is something wrong with how I'm defining the dates.

```
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ';
var testTime = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 05:33:19 GMT+0000', format);
var startPeriod = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 04:00:19 GMT+0000', format);
var endPeriod = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 10:00:19 GMT+0000', format);

console.log(
    testTime.isBetween(startPeriod, endPeriod)
);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `moment()` takes in the format that the first parameter is currently in. This looks incorrect. You can verify this by logging the times individually and seeing that they're incorrect (probably 1970)

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/

Infact, you should be able to drop this second parameter completely as the input date is in a standard format already (an ISO string).

```
var testTime = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 05:33:19 GMT+0000');
var startPeriod = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 04:00:19 GMT+0000');
var endPeriod = moment('Thu Jun 27 2019 10:00:19 GMT+0000');

console.log(
    testTime.isBetween(startPeriod, endPeriod)
);
```

Comment: The dates are in a weird format (month, day, year). Moment.js won't like this.

Comment: I'm talking about the dates in the original question/your answer. Try running the exact code in your answer (with moment available) and look at the console output, there's a deprecation warning. Don't worry about it at this point, OP seems to be happy.